# ASP .NET performance of singleton controllers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, singleton, unity-container

To my understanding if I use the default controller factory, a new instance of a controller will be constructed for each request. That means that if I have 100000 requests, objects have to be created than destroyed therefore layers under too (if others layers aren't singleton not the point here).

Couldn't it be in term of performance interesting to pass the controllers as singleton to eliminate the time of creation/destruction of these same controllers ?

Looking at answers i'm editing my question to be more precise.
This is my controller in singleton. At it's starting I get a new dbcontext which lives while the thread is up. When all my transaction is finished the dbcontext is disposed.

```
controller(){
  using(create new dbcontext){
    doing things
    transaction stuffs... 
    doing things
    transaction stuffs...
  }
}
```

So I don't have any connections to db open for ever, and I just need the payload of my POST request. I'm not saying it's not a issue to take in notice, I actually did took care of them.
So could I get a performance boost ? I can't really test this in real life. It's just for me to know. Did somebody test this ?

Bonus question :
If I use the default controller factory (1 request 1 controller) are objects created in the controller (ex: dbcontext, etc. ) destroyed when controller gets killed ?
Is there a "magical" thingy in the case I "forget" the using ? Or do I have to wait for the garbage collector (no bueno) ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Each request should be stateless I think.

Comment: Singleton controllers doesn't make sense to me. They have scoped dependencies such as `HttpContext` or even database services that need an a database connection for each request.

Comment: using singletons to handle concurrent requests may have another impact on performance :) so it can be faster on this aspect but slower on another aspect. I don't think the framework designers could miss such a simple point in improving the performance.

Comment: In terms of your specific question `Couldn't it be in term of performance interesting to pass the controllers as singleton to eliminate the time of creation/destruction of these same controllers ?` the answer is `Yes`. It could be interesting.

Comment: @Jesus lopez thanks for you answers : i'm using Entity Framework a dbcontext is injected with the "perthread" mode (unity injection) and the pattern localthread, so i should be ok database speaking. Also I know it is possible i have done it and it works but is it better than before, this i don't know

Comment: @Mjwills could you develop a bit ?

Comment: @IgorBeaufils It could be _interesting_. It wouldn't be _useful_ though - as the other comments state.

Comment: `i'm using Entity Framework a dbcontext is injected with the "perthread" mode (unity injection)` This is not a good idea (read - terrible idea), since the container will not know when you've finished using the connection. It will be holding the connection open _far_ too long. You should scope it to the http request. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954586/unitofwork-repository-database-connection-issue This may be working for you now, sure. But your app will perform absolutely horribly under load. Database connections in .NET are supposed to be short lived.

Comment: Effectively the trade off you have made is to have cheap, small things (controllers) created less often (thus saving you some allocations, but causing all manner of weird oddities since the framework effectively assumes everything is scoped to the a http request), but are holding expensive, large things (database connections) open **way** longer. This is _not_ a good trade off

Comment: `objects have to be created than destroyed therefore layers under too` No, this isn't true. It depends on how they are registered with the container (as you have identified). If you want the dependencies to not be created repeatedly and they don't have any http request / context based state then register them as singletons. But it is odd to make the controller itself a singleton, since it often _does_ have some form of http request based state (body, query string etc etc).

Comment: @mjwills Not sure we understood each other, I might not have been clear enough. I'll try to be a bit more in my edit. But thanks for your answers

Comment: `So could I get a performance boost ?` https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: `using(create new dbcontext){` This is not how you should be doing things. You should be DIing in your dependencies. But definitely _not_ using `"perthread" mode` like you said you are doing (which contradicts the code in your question, but anyway).

Comment: `Couldn't it be in term of performance interesting to pass the controllers as singleton to eliminate the time of creation/destruction of these same controllers ?` Yes, it could be _interesting_. Is it _worth it_? No, almost certainly not - since newing up your controllers is very unlikely to be the bottleneck in your system.

Comment: `If I use the default controller factory (1 request 1 controller) are objects created in the controller (ex: dbcontext, etc. ) destroyed when controller gets killed ?` It depends how you registered them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40418462/34092 Unity is, unfortunately, a pretty crap IoC container. I'd recommend using a different one (like Autofac) which works OOTB "better".

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers i'll look into it especially "Autofac".

Comment: Actually I wrote it wrong but it's not the dbcontext that is in "perthread" mode but a dbContextHolder to who I ask to init a dbcontext in the controller (just after the using). So I can call dbContextHolder.getContext() in under layers (doing a resolve with unity). I'm still in same thread so I have my dbContextHolder and my initiated dbContext...

Comment: Fundamentally though, Unity is not very good - so you are forced to do things in weird ways. Autofac has much saner defaults. Stuff "just works" far more often.